# Configure solrnet with Solr

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud, solrnet, sunspot-solr

Is it necessary to use tomcat for configuring Solr with asp.net.
by this link [link]https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/480091/Using-Solr-for-Search-with-NET-Csharp
i configured and it works!! but it uses solr 1.4 version and i want to update my solr version.
And [link]https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Running+Solr+on+Tomcat
it says that you cannot configure the tomcat with version 5 or latest from it.
so how to configure asp.net with solr latest version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest Solr runs as standalone black box. Do not look at ancient tutorials for Tomcat information, they are not useful anymore. And it is a separate issue from connecting to it via .NET client.

For the client part, the source-code version of SolrNet is more up to date. And it should work with latest Solr, with the main issue being that the URL for Solr now **must** include collection name, so  http://localhost:8983/solr/collectionname . Check for parameters to set core or collection or similar.

There is also [Solr Express](http://solr-express.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) you may want to have a look at.